# How do I organize my inventory?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How do I arrange my inventory in TF2? I've noticed some people's backups have a page for stranges, a page for uniques, etc.  Everytime I sort my backpack based on Quality though, when I view my Steam BP online, it still shows up as unoragnized and jumbled up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag and drop.

Though, your TF2 inventory and your Steam inventory are not the same thing.  There is a delay in synchronization.

If you know you moved the items, but it doesn't look right outside of TF2, just wait a few hours.